# How to resize partition using TWRP, and is it safe?

Tags: samsung, twrp, partitions

I tried to flash an Android 12 GSI on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 8.0 (SM-T330NU) from [here](https://github.com/phhusson/treble_experimentations/releases) (system-squeak-arm32 binder 64-ab-vndklite-gogapps.img.xz), so I extracted the img file which was 1.8GB and tried to flash it not knowing there is a limit for ROM size, so it told me that the file is too large for the target device, then I found out a way to resize the system partition by going to wipe -> choose/check "System" -> resize file system, but is that safe and will it work?